# No post content is showing up in the wordpress edit textarea

Tags: wordpress

I replaced my WordPress TinyMCE editor with a custom textarea field. Everything works well when saving the post but whenever I want to edit the post, the textarea field goes blank.

I just want to ask if there is any hook I have to call to make the post display for editing in the textarea field.

If there is any hook, please guide me.

**EDIT**

Here is the code which I used to add my own text area:

```
/* Remove tinymce editor */         
    function wpdocs_remove_post_type_support() {
        remove_post_type_support( 'post', 'editor' );
    }

    add_action('init' ,'wpdocs_remove_post_type_support' );


    /* Add my own textarea */ 
    function myprefix_edit_form_advanced() {


    require('texteditor.html'); 


    }   


    add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', 'myprefix_edit_form_advanced' );
```

Comment: Hey dear ,
can you please add code which you have used, so i can refer you solution from your code OR able to suggest another solution.

Comment: @maulik You should check the above edited post.